# Random variable bounded by another random variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

> How to find $\Pr(z<X<Y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent exponential r.v.'s with parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$

So $x$ is bounded by $z$ and $y$, and y must be go from $z$, (and not from $0$) to infinity, I tried:

$\displaystyle\int_z^{\infty}\mu e^{-\mu y}\int_z^y\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dxdy=\int_z^{\infty}\mu e^{-\mu y}(e^{-\lambda z}-e^{-\lambda y})dy$

$\displaystyle=e^{-\lambda z}\int_z^{\infty}\mu e^{-\mu y}dy-\int_z^{\infty}\mu e^{-y(\lambda+\mu)}dy=e^{-\lambda z}(-e^{-\mu y}\bigg|_z^{\infty})-(\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}e^{-(\lambda+\mu )y}\bigg|_z^{\infty}$

$\large=e^{-z(\lambda+\mu)}-\frac{\mu}{\mu+\lambda}e^{-z(\lambda+\mu)}=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}e^{-z(\lambda+\mu)}$

Is my solution correct ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is correct. It can be done more efficiently by: 
$$P\left\{ z<X<Y\right\} =\int_{z}^{\infty}f_{X}\left(x\right)P\left\{ z<X<Y\mid X=x\right\} dx=\lambda\int_{z}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\mu x}dx=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}e^{-\left(\lambda+\mu\right)z}$$

Comment: $P(z<X<Y|X=x)$ looks a bit more complicated, do you consider here only the case $\{X<Y\}$, since $x$ goes from $z$, thus $\{z<X\}$ holds automatically and use $\int_x^\infty\mu e^{-\mu y}=e^{-\mu y}$ ?

Comment: For every $x$ that satisfies $x>z$  we have $P\left\{ z<X<Y\mid X=x\right\} =P\left\{ z<x<Y\right\} =P\left\{ x<Y\right\} =e^{-\mu x}$.

Comment: One warning might be on its place: the independence of $X$ and $Y$ plays a role here. Things would have been different if e.g. $X=Y$.

Comment: Given conditions unchanged, how to compute $P(X<z<Y)$?

Comment: You already asked and also received an answer to that question.

Comment: @drhab What I really want to ask is, if $X$ is bounded by $Y$, how to find $P(X<x)$?

Comment: @Bloodmoon Do you mean  $P(X<x\mid X<Y)$? That is the probability that  $X<x$ **under condition** that $X<Y$.

Comment: @drhab Sorry that I am not good at math. I am abstracting a physical system, and I am not sure if I should use $P(X<x\mid X<Y)$ or $P(X<Y<x)$ to describe it before I find their expressions and verify through simulation. Now let's say $P(X<x\mid X<Y)$, how do I compute it?

Comment: @Bloodmoon In general $P(A\mid B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$ and this can be applied to get: $P(X<x\mid X<Y)=P(X<x\wedge X<Y)/P(X<Y)$. Actually it is not the right policy to answer questions like this in a comment. Why don't you ask a decent question about it that includes your doubts?

Comment: @drhab I have asked a question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415085/distribution-of-a-random-variable-bounded-by-another-random-variable. Do you mind take a look?